# React re-render component when another component is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React source files, `A` and `B`.
`A`, in its render method, calls `B` like this:

```
{this.state.classificationSelected
      ?
      <div>
      <B classification={this.props.categories[this.state.categoryIndex].classes[this.state.classificationIndex]} ref="B"/>
      </div>
      :
      null
    }
```

So `B` is rendered if the `Classification` component of `A` is selected.

In `B`, I have the following method which computes some values based on A's `Classification`:

```
getSingleChoiceAttributes: function() {
    var singleChoiceAttributes = [];
    for(let attribute of this.props.classification.attributes){
        if(attribute.attributeType == 'SingleChoice') {
            singleChoiceAttributes.push(attribute);
        }
    }
    return singleChoiceAttributes;
},
```

Currently, I am calling this method from B's `ComponentWillMount` method.

I would like this method to get executed every time `A`'s classification is changed. However, for now it is called only when `A`'s classification is first selected.

How can I make the `getSingleChoiceAttributes` method change every time `A`'s `Classification`(represented by `this.state.classificationIndex`) is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops).

```
void componentWillReceiveProps(
  object nextProps
)
```

> Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not
>   called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before
>   render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The
>   old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState()
>   within this function will not trigger an additional render.